# Why does Mock.SetupAllProperties throw a constructor exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq

I'm using Moq to drive my Model-View-Presenter unit tests.  The particular view I'm testing is composed of a subview, which is modeled as an interface as illustrated here:

```
public interface ICustomerView:IView{

    public int CustomerId {get;set;}
    public IDateRangeView DateRangeView {get;set;}

}
```

In certain tests, I don't care to test the behavior or interaction with IDateRangeView; I simply want any invocations of that property not to throw null references exceptions, etc.  It looks like Moq supports this feature by setting DefaultValue of a mock to DefaultValue.Mock, and then calling SetupAllProperties:

```
[Test]
public void some_test(){

     var mockView = new Mock<ICustomerView>() { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };
     mockView.SetupAllProperties();
}
```

However, the call to SetupAllProperties throws this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
  Message="A matching constructor for the given arguments was not found on the mocked type."
  Source="Moq"
  StackTrace:
       at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__0()
       at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Action action)
       at Moq.Mock`1.InitializeInstance()
       at Moq.Mock`1.get_Object()
       at Moq.Mock`1.GetObject()
       at Moq.Mock.get_Object()
       at Moq.MockDefaultValueProvider.ProvideDefault(MethodInfo member, Object[] arguments)
       at Moq.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass27.<SetupAllProperties>b__23()
       at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Action action)
       at Moq.Mock.SetupAllProperties(Mock mock)
       at Moq.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass27.<SetupAllProperties>b__23()
       at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke(Action action)
       at Moq.Mock.SetupAllProperties(Mock mock)
       at Moq.Mock`1.SetupAllProperties()

  InnerException: System.MissingMethodException
       Message="Constructor on type 'DateRangeProxyf68a22c875334e7d858d8ccc5759ecaa' not found."
       Source="mscorlib"
       StackTrace:
            at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
            at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
            at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, Object[] constructorArguments, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
            at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, ProxyGenerationOptions options, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
            at Castle.DynamicProxy.ProxyGenerator.CreateClassProxy(Type classToProxy, Type[] additionalInterfacesToProxy, IInterceptor[] interceptors)
            at Moq.Mock`1.<InitializeInstance>b__0()
       InnerException:
```

My work around is to set such interfaces manually, but there must be a less tedious solution:

```
 [Test]
    public void some_test(){

         var mockView = new Mock<ICustomerView>();
         var viewDateMock = new Mock<IDateRangeView>();
         mockView.SetupGet(v=>v.DateRangeView).Returns(viewDateMock.Object);
    }
```

**Versions/Environment**

Moq 3.1.416.3
.NET Framework 3.5
nUnit 2.5.0.9122
VS 2008 + Windows 7 x64

Comment: Sorry, you can chalk this one up to user error.  The exception being thrown is accurate.  One of the properties on IDateRangeView (DateRange), is indeed missing a parameterless constructor.  I guess I was expecting SetupAllProperties to only create auto mocks on the immediate children of the Mock in question, and not attempt to mock out the entire object graph.